# GPS doesn't fix seeing 16 satellites

Tags: gps

I'm receiving odd NMEA responses when trying to use GPS:

> $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
>
> $GPGSV,4,1,16,05,,,,14,,,,11,,,,02,,,*79
>
> $GPGSV,4,2,16,23,,,,28,,,,12,,,,01,,,*71
>
> $GPGSV,4,3,16,32,,,,30,,,,27,,,,26,,,*7A
>
> $GPGSV,4,4,16,21,,,,13,,,,04,,,,03,,,*78
>
> $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
>
> $PQXFI,,,,,,,,,,*56
>
> $GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
>
> $GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
>
> $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
>
> $GPGSV,4,1,16,27,,,,03,,,,05,,,,14,,,*7D
>
> $GPGSV,4,2,16,11,,,,02,,,,23,,,,28,,,*71
>
> $GPGSV,4,3,16,12,,,,01,,,,32,,,,30,,,*79
>
> $GPGSV,4,4,16,26,,,,21,,,,13,,,,04,,,*7F
>
> $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
>
> $PQXFI,,,,,,,,,,*56
>
> $GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
>
> $GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
>
> $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

and it goes like this on and on, changing only the values in lines beginning with $GPGSV. The device is DW 5620 in Alienware M14x notebook, 3G connection is possible to establish, but it doesn't affect responses shown above. The output is the same in- & outdoors. Could anyone interpret this log, so I would know whether it's a software or hardware issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first look at the $GPRMC message: it does not show any data, further it shows status "V" which means invalid fix. Your gps has not yet a valid position.

So move up from your desk, go out and place the laptop such that it has good view ro open sky. (e.g put it on the roof of a car, or similar and wait, the first time wait for 40 minutes., later it needs only 40s)

Your receiver does not see 16 satellites. GPGSV tells which sattelites are theoretical in view on sky. and you see that there is no SNR (signal to noise ratio) contained for any sattelite.

Comment: First of all, thanks for help :) But as I said the same response I get waiting in open sky and indoors.

Comment: see my update related to GSV

Comment: Yes, I understand those messages, but I can't understand why the GPS always says it's (theoretically) seeing 16 satellites. It doesn't matter where am I or how long it's looking - always similar to $GPGSV,4,1,16,27,,,,03,,,,05,,,,14,,,*7D etc. Shouldn't it sometimes say something different according to visibility?

Comment: The receiver has no time, no position, it has an initial almanach; Forget the GSv sentences, there is no time, without time, nothing is valid. wait if you have a valid position, or find out why you dont get one.

Comment: So you're saying that GPS can't see ANY sats eventually. So if it's giving these logs in clear sky, does it mean gps module is working fine but can't find sats? So it means e.g. antennae/bad range issue or could these mean that the module itself is malfunctioning? - That is what I'm trying to find out given such strange logs. Because I don't know if I'm looking on bad firmware/software or hardware issue. Could these be clearly determined from logs I presented? - Gratitude for Your help so far.

Comment: Fron the logs: the communication to GPS chip seems to work, the GPS chip seems to work; It looks like, that the GPS antenna is defect, or disabled.

Comment: Thank you very very much! That's exactly what I needed to be assured of. I will now try 1 hour session outdoors with wi-fi antennae plugged to gps modem and with antennae out of laptop casing and see if anything changes in logs. Maybe it's some kind of disturbance (in the Force :) caused by interference with other devices in the casing. Thank You very very much AlexWien!